# Web-Based Application Development

Tags: android, android-webview

I need to make an Android app that will take data from my college website and display it on an Android device (basically a mobile version of the website), something like Pulse does, UK & World News etc. etc.

What is the best way to go about this? Webview? Or is there another, better option that I'm yet missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best bet is to use one of the javascript mobile development frameworks such as Titanium, Sencha Touch, PhoneGap, jQuery Mobile, etc.

Comment: Wow...thanks. I'll look into them. It's a bit embarassing, but this is really new to me...

Comment: It's all still pretty new! If you did want to stay native, then you definitely can have your entire app be a webview that loads a website. Pretty sure thats how Titanium and such works, they just automate that part for you.

Comment: Personally I would recommend Sencha Touch to develop the site and then PhoneGap to create the app for the site. It's tried and true, and imo the quickest way to get professional results.

Comment: The website's already developed, it's up and running for some time.

Comment: I'll try with Sencha Touch / Phone Gap first when I start work on that and let you know how things are going. Thanks a lot for your help! I love how things get answered and people take their time on Stack Overflow to explain to noobs like me:)) Thanks again!